# Select users with specific number of orders pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with `user_id` and `order_number` columns. `order_number` tells the nth order by a user. I want to select users who have done certain number of orders.

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
user_id order_number
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   2   1
4   2   2
5   3   1
6   3   2
7   3   3
```

**Output:** `[1,3]`
Output should be `user_id` `[1,3]` because they have done 3 orders but 2 have done only 2 orders.

I am trying:

```py
(df.groupby(['user_id'])['order_number'].max()==3)
```

This gives me boolean series but how to select index with only True values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general way of doing this is by using [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.groupby(['user_id'],as_index=False)['order_number'].max().query("order_number==3")
#or
df.groupby(['user_id'],as_index=False)['order_number'].max().loc[
                                   lambda x: x['order_number']==3]
```

For this example you dont have to get max of another column, you can just count them, as @Steven suggests :

```
df.groupby('user_id',as_index=False).count().query("order_number==3")
```

Or as @Wen suggests:

```
df['user_id'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x==3]
```

---

```
   user_id  order_number
0        1             3
2        3             3
```

Comment: Should probably show an example using `count()` as well, since that's a more reliable solution (even though it wasn't what was asked for)

Comment: Thanks for this. Didn't knew that we can also use lambda functions inside `.loc[]` and also about the `.query()` function.

Comment: @techytushar the benefit of going with `count` over `max` is that if you have bad data (e.g. a given user's order numbers go 1, 2, 4), you will still be able to match users with 3 distinct orders (`count()` for `[1,2,4]` is `3`).

Comment: Thank You @StevenMoseley for the insights, that is indeed true. I'll use `count()` then. I am working on the InstaCart dataset on Kaggle.

Comment: Hold on , why not use value_counts ?~ :-)

Comment: @YOandBEN_W updated my answer. At the start this looked like how to do a `.loc[]` on groupby. Thanks for your suggestion. Happy New year :)

Comment: @anky_91 happy new year :-) 